# can't specialize parent class methods when using Sub::Exporter in a module subclassing a module using Sub::Exporter

Tags: perl

I'm trying to extend a class (`mA`) which is using `Sub::Exporter`.  I'd like to use `Sub::Exporter` in the subclass (`mB`).  I can't figure out how to pass the options unique to `mA` through the call to `Sub::Exporter` in `mB`.  Here's some test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;


{
    package mA;

    use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
            exports => { gmorn => \&build_gmorn },
        };

    sub build_gmorn {
        my ( $class, $name, $arg ) = @_;
        return sub { say "$arg->{salutation}"; }
    }

    sub new { return bless {}, shift }
}

{
    package mB;

    use parent -norequire, 'mA';

    use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
        exports => { gnite => \&build_gnite },
    };

    sub build_gnite {
        my ( $class, $name, $arg ) = @_;
        return sub { say "$arg->{salutation}"; }
    }
}

{
    package mFr;

    use parent -norequire, 'mB';

    mB->import(
       gmorn => { salutation => 'Bon Jour' },
       gnite => { salutation => 'Bon Nuit' }
    );

}

my $obj = mFr->new;

$obj->gmorn();
$obj->gnite();
```

The result is:

```
% perl t
"gmorn" is not exported by the mB module at t line 66.
```

Is there any way of inheriting `Sub::Exporter` specifications?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing object-oriented perl, it is a *very bad idea* to import symbols from one package into another. The inheritance the Perl's standard mechanism will work fine, and all you seem to be doing here is renaming the imported methods.

The problem is that `use parent` doesn't call the other package's `import` routine, so `build_gmorn` is never imported into `mB` as `gmorn`.

In addition, as your error message says, `gmorn` is not exported by the `mB` module, so it cannot be imported into `mFr`.

If you change `mB` to look like this then your code will mostly work. Note that because there is no `mA.pm` I have had to write `mA->import('gmorn')` as the correct `use mA 'gmorn'` would fail.

```
package mB;

mA->import('gmorn');
use parent -norequire, 'mA';

use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
    exports => {
        gmorn => undef,
        gnite => \&build_gnite 
    }
};

sub build_gnite {
    my ( $class, $name, $arg ) = @_;
    return sub { say "$arg->{salutation}"; }
}
```

---

**Update**

There is no way to get the parameters to `use Sub::Exporter` to "pass through" multiple levels of `use`, because the `import` subroutine needs to call the generator function. So in your example `mB::import` needs to call `mA::build_gmorn` but it has no knowledge of that subroutine so it cannot be done.

The only convenient solution is to export *both* the generator and a generated subroutine, so that the calling code can either use the function or export a generated function itself.

This set of programs works fine.

**mA.pm**

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;

package mA;

use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
    exports => [
        'build_gmorn',
        gmorn => \&build_gmorn,
    ]
};

sub build_gmorn {
    my ( $class, $name, $arg ) = @_;
    return sub { say "$arg->{salutation}"; }
}

1;
```

**mB.pm**

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;

package mB;

use mA qw/ gmorn build_gmorn /;
use parent 'mA';

use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
    exports => [
        'build_gmorn', 
        gmorn => \&build_gmorn,
        'build_gnite', 
        gnite => \&build_gnite
    ]
};

sub build_gnite {
    my ( $class, $name, $arg ) = @_;
    return sub { say "$arg->{salutation}"; }
}

1;
```

**mFr.pl**

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;

package mFr;

use parent 'mB';

mB->import(
   gmorn => { salutation => 'Bon Jour' },
   gnite => { salutation => 'Bon Nuit' }
);

sub new { return bless {}, shift }

my $obj = mFr->new;

$obj->gmorn();
$obj->gnite();
```

**output**

```
Bon Jour
Bon Nuit
```

Comment: I think you've overlooked the fact that I'm specializing the methods, not simply renaming them. (That's the only reason I'm using Sub::Exporter). They *have* to be imported into the sub classes so that they get the specialized versions.  The error message that I report is coming from Sub::Exporter, not from Perl itself.  That's why I'm asking about inheritance of Sub::Exporter specifications. (added in edit: You're code doesn't allow specializing the `gmorn` method).

Comment: @DiabJerius: I have added to my answer what I think is the only solution

Comment: Thanks. Another approach is to explicitly construct an exporter via Sub::Exporter::build_exporter, use a custom import() to strip known arguments out of the import list, pass them to the local exporter and pass the rest to the super class's import(). That would solve the problem of needing to know what the superclass is doing.  It does require reproducing much of what's in Sub::Exporter::build_exporter. What I'd really like is a "pass_through" mode as in Getopt::Long, which would remove identified options from the import list.  I'd simply pass the rest up to the parent's import.